# I am making an app which if you click on a button an audio will play but the audio is not playing in last two buttons

Tags: java, android, button, audio

I am making an app which if you click on a button an audio will play but the audio is not playing in last two buttons and can you also please tell me how can I stop the audio if I click on the audio button again ?? Here's The Full Code. Thanks in Advance. It's in gdsph_btn & aspamm_btn

```
package com.agrimplayz.radhasoamipaath;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button rrjk_btn, gdsph_btn, aspamm, stop_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rrjk_btn = findViewById(R.id.rrjk_btn);
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.radhasoami_rakshak_jeev_ke);

    rrjk_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           if(counter == 2)
               mediaPlayer.pause();
           mediaPlayer.start();


            gdsph_btn = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, 
R.raw.guru_dhara_sheesh_par_haath);

            final MediaPlayer finalMediaPlayer1 = mediaPlayer;
            gdsph_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finalMediaPlayer1.start();
                }
            });


            aspamm = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, 
R.raw.ae_satguru_pita_aur_malik_mere);

            final MediaPlayer finalMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
            aspamm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finalMediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it intentional for the rest of the code to be inside your rrjk_btn click listener?

Comment: @lyncx No Bro  It wasn't Intentional

Comment: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: yes that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button rrjk_btn, gdsph_btn, aspamm, stop_btn;
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radhasoami_rakshak_jeev_ke);
        rrjk_btn = findViewById(R.id.rrjk_btn);
        rrjk_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (counter == 2)
                {
                    mediaPlayer1.pause();
                }
                mediaPlayer1.start();
                counter++;
            }
        });
        //
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.guru_dhara_sheesh_par_haath);
        gdsph_btn = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
        gdsph_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer2.start();
            }
        });
        //
        aspamm = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ae_satguru_pita_aur_malik_mere);
        aspamm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer3.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Working properly But how can i stop it ??

Comment: hi Agru,I think this question has been resolved, and you're asking a new question.If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and provide which button do you want to use to stop. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.